# How can I send email from my local host using yahoo mail account?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, yahoo

I am developing an ASP.NET website using Visual studio 2010 ultimate. I want to send mail for confirmation to the clients using my yahoo mail account. How can I do so ? what settings should I change or add ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Yahoo mail settings

- Yahoo! Mail SMTP server address: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
- Yahoo! Mail SMTP user name: Your full Yahoo! Mail email address
  (including "@yahoo.com")
- Yahoo! Mail SMTP password: Your Yahoo! Mail password
- Yahoo! Mail SMTP port: 465
- Yahoo! Mail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

Here is a sample code to send email using yahoo mail settings

```
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@yahoo.com","*******"); 
emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
emailClient.Port = 465;

MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("xyz@gmail.com", "someone@something.something", "fire!!", "Call up 911 and inform my house is on fire and my phone too");
emailClient.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have smtp/pop access to yahoo mail in order to send the mail using yahoo account. The free account offered by yahoo does not have that access. You might have to opt for yahoo mail pro.

For sending a mail using SMTP, all you need is username and password of an smtp account. You will use the pass this credentials and send the mail with classes system.net.mail namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1684/Sending-Mail-Using-C-via-SMTP

There you will see how to setup configuration to send a mail using any (in your case yahoo) smtp server to send an email.